# Google In-APP Purchase Request After reinstalling APP

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I implemented Google in App. its working fine after publishing the app. but i am facing a problem . When user install the app and then purchase the items and then uninstall the app and reinstall it and goes to the purchased items then app agian lock the purchsed item and ask for purchase request. is there any problem in OnRestoreTransaction? 
I used code from the Google In app Purchse site.
Here is the code :

```
 private class DungeonsPurchaseObserver extends PurchaseObserver {
        public DungeonsPurchaseObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(in_app.this, handler);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBillingSupported(boolean supported) {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "supported: " + supported);
            }
            if (supported) {
                restoreDatabase();  

            } else {
                showDialog(DIALOG_BILLING_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId,
                int quantity, long purchaseTime, String developerPayload) {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onPurchaseStateChange() itemId: " + itemId + " " + purchaseState);
            }

            if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED ) {
                finish();
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onRequestPurchaseResponse(RequestPurchase request,
                ResponseCode responseCode) {
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, request.mProductId + ": " + responseCode);
            }
            if (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK) {
                if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "purchase was successfully sent to server");
                }
            } else if (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_USER_CANCELED) {
                if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "user canceled purchase");
                }
            } else {
                if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "purchase failed");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRestoreTransactionsResponse(RestoreTransactions request,
                ResponseCode responseCode) {
            if (responseCode == ResponseCode.RESULT_OK) {
                if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "completed RestoreTransactions request");
                }
                // Update the shared preferences so that we don't perform
                // a RestoreTransactions again.
                SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putBoolean(DB_INITIALIZED, true);
                edit.commit();
            } else {
                if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "RestoreTransactions error: " + responseCode);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.in_app);

        mHandler = new Handler();
        mDungeonsPurchaseObserver = new DungeonsPurchaseObserver(mHandler);
        mBillingService = new BillingService();
        mBillingService.setContext(this);

        mPurchaseDatabase = new PurchaseDatabase(this);
        //setupWidgets();

        // Check if billing is supported.
        ResponseHandler.register(mDungeonsPurchaseObserver);
        if (!mBillingService.checkBillingSupported()) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_CANNOT_CONNECT_ID);
        }



        purchase=(Button) findViewById(R.id.purchase);
        cancel=(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);

        purchase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(!ownedItems.contains("android.test.refunded")){      
                    if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "buying: " + "  product" + " Product Name: " + "Product");
                    }

                    if (!mBillingService.requestPurchase("android.test.refunded", mPayloadContents)) {
                        showDialog(DIALOG_BILLING_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
                    }
            }
            }
        });
```

**Edited:**

I call this in onCrearte of in-app java file :
this first checks that whehter the current user purchased the item for which he is demanding and if not then iniate request for Purchase.
In onPurchsestateChanged i only checked that state is Purchased or not.

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.in_app);

```
    mHandler = new Handler();
    mDungeonsPurchaseObserver = new DungeonsPurchaseObserver(mHandler);
    mBillingService = new BillingService();
    mBillingService.setContext(this);

    mPurchaseDatabase = new PurchaseDatabase(this);
    //setupWidgets();

    // Check if billing is supported.
    ResponseHandler.register(mDungeonsPurchaseObserver);
    if (!mBillingService.checkBillingSupported()) {
        showDialog(DIALOG_CANNOT_CONNECT_ID);
    }
    System.out.println("for check"+getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(DB_INITIALIZED, false));

    if (getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(DB_INITIALIZED, false)) {
        System.out.println(mBillingService.restoreTransactions());
    }
    else{
    purchase=(Button) findViewById(R.id.purchase);
    cancel=(Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel);

    purchase.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!ownedItems.contains("android.test.refunded")){      
                if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "buying: " + " product" + " Product Name: " + "i");
                }


                if (!mBillingService.requestPurchase("android.test.refunded", mPayloadContents)) {
                    showDialog(DIALOG_BILLING_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
                }
        }
        }
    });


    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(in_app.this, Main.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_right);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

**OnPurchaseStateChanged:**

```
    public void onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState purchaseState, String itemId,
            int quantity, long purchaseTime, String developerPayload) {

        if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPurchaseStateChange() itemId: " + itemId + " " + purchaseState);
        }
        System.out.println("here for new fun");
        if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED ) {

            finish();
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,BodyParts1.class);
            context.startActivity(intent1);
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to restore all purchased items you have to explicitly call `mBillingService.restoreTransactions()`. Then you will receive `onPurchaseStateChange` callback for each previously purchased item.

Put this code in `onCreate` method and it should work well:

```
if (!getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(DB_INITIALIZED, false)) {
    mBillingService.restoreTransactions();
}
```

Comment: thankyou for the help.. where i have to call this function in my above code ? means when app start this function should run for checking purchased item for this specific user. Second i am testing in app on testing account so did this account can identify that this item has been purchased??

Comment: i call this in my in-app file . but this function giving false and its not executing  mBillingService.restoreTransactions(); i printed it  for checking that what value is returning         System.out.println("for check"+getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(DB_INITIALIZED, false)); and its returning value is (false)

Comment: actually i am checking all these activities on my test account

Comment: oooops, i have made a mistake. It should be `if (!getPreferences(...))`. I've updated my answer

Comment: Do you have any items purchased with your test account?

Comment: yes did that but when this part is executed onPurchasedChange state is not called

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22437/discussion-between-akhter-and-vmironov)